# Use the "new" keyword to create an object using reflection

Tags: c#, class, object, reflection, keyword

I'm completely new to reflection and I'm trying to call a class name from a db record and then load the class and run it but I'm pulling my hair out on where I'm going wrong, its probably something really silly I'm missing.

As an example I have my class in a different project and scripts folder, then call the name of it from the db record.

```
className = String.Format("Utilities.Scripts.{0}", script.ScriptClass);
```

Then in my main program I have

```
// Get a type from the string 
Type type = Type.GetType(className);

// Create an instance of that type
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Retrieve the method you are looking for
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("start");

// Invoke the method on the instance we created above
methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
```

But I am getting the error as when debugging I can see my details passed into the GetType(className) but nothing goes through to the type and as such into the obj where it is erroring.

Comment: can you post your exact error?

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException - {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type"} 

Thanks

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and figure out what methods you are calling with null arguments. Then, make them not null. My first guess would be to make the second argument to methodInfo.Invoke() an empty array instead of null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the [Assembly Qualified Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) of the type (as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)) since the class is in a different project.  Also, make sure that the assembly you are trying to load the type from is either in the same folder as the assembly trying to load it, or in the GAC.

For a class defined as below:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

The full class name is `Foo.Bar.Class1`.  The assembly qualified name also specifies the full name of the assembly, as in `Foo.Bar.Class1, Foo.Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35`.  You can find the Assembly Qualified Name of your type with somthing like:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Foo.Bar.Class1).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

Comment: Isn't this what I am doing though by putting in the project, sub folder and then class name in as the type?

"Utilities.Scripts.{0}", script.ScriptClass"

When debugging this is showing fine, but you hover over the type and its got nothing?

Thanks

Comment: No, any relation between the Assembly Qualified Name and ProjectName.Folder.ClassName is incidental.  I will edit my answer to more clearly define Assembly Qualified Name.

Comment: Thats great! Solved my problem and loading my 2 test classes if I change the db ordering. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(className);
```

In that this particular overload of the method will not throw an exception when the type cannot be resolved. Instead use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d.aspx) which takes 2 booleans, one of which being `throwOnError`. Pass true for this parameter and you will get an exception which should help you debug why your type cannnot be resolved from the string you pass in.

I suspect you need a class name *and* assembly name

```
Utilities.Scripts.SomeClass, SomeAssemblyName
```